# How to (quickly) count the number of rows in ArcGIS attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How can I quickly see how many rows of data are in my attribute table in a large file without having to scroll right down to the bottom?

Is there a way of removing the * so that I can quickly see total?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a button in the bottom left corner of your attribute table for move to end.
[image]
This button will take the table to the last row and recalculate the screen to show number of rows.

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in tool called [Get Count (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) that counts rows.  Simply input the path to your feature class and the tool yields a row count.

[image]

Comment: This method will probably yield better performance than the other popular answer (using >| on the table) if you are dealing with tables containing millions of rows or more.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your attribute table into a .gdb will remove the * and show you the total number of rows.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if the number of records exceeds 2000. Maybe there's a setting somewhere to change this?

Comment: There is, but it won't improve performance, and you'd still need to move to the end of the table to be sure.

Comment: I've got tables, feature classes, etc in a .gdb and with millions of records they show the total amount without needing to read all the records (clicking >| arrow).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version you are using but in ArcMap 10.2.2

Select all your rows. Then on the Selection Menu Click Statistics, which will open the selection statistics window, select a field in the table, You will see the Count in the statistics window.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the ->| arrow to move to the last record. Then the tagline at the bottom of the attribute table will say something like (0 out of 952 selected)